# Replace Rogue Wave Software Components With Open Source OR Standard Classes

Tags: c++, class, replace, standards

I have a requirement where in i need to replace/remove rogue wave classes like RWCString, RWBoolean, RWCollectable etc. Is there any opensource/standard C++ classes which replaces rogue wave? OR Do i need to extend standard C++ classes(By inheriting them to my own classes)?

Answer (score 0):

Eg. `RWCString` is a wrapper of standard `std::string`, accoring to the docs (http://docs.roguewave.com/sourcepro/11/html/toolsref/rwcstring.html),
but with some more methods.

If you have to get rid of it, you´ll need to rewrite it. You can´t replace it with `std::string` itself, because it lacks the additional stuff, and you shouldn´t inherit from std::string (some possible problems).

If you don´t want to rewrite it, the even more tedious possibility is to change every part of your program where strings are used.

Same goes for the other classes.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply...
If i replace RWCString with std::string then i need to do a lot of modifications in my source. I thought that there could be an RWCString equivalent open source class to replace it.